# TIdNNTP fallback to XOVER for legacy/non-compliant NNTP server

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy

I am using `TIdNNTP` and encountered a situation with news.astraweb.com server where it announces in `LIST EXTENSIONS` that it supports new command `HDR` and `OVER` (formal versions of `XHDR` and `XOVER`) - see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3977#section-8.3 and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2980#section-2.8

The problem is that the server replies with command code 500 (invalid command) when issued OVER command (instead of XOVER). Although this is clearly non-RFC-compliant behavior I'd like to see if there is a possibility to force `TIdNNTP` to use XOVER instead of OVER, in other words to work in a sort of "legacy" mode. The same thing works perfectly with compliant server like news.aioe.org

Log example from news.astraweb.com (problematic server)

```
->CAPABILITIES
<-500 What?
->LIST EXTENSIONS
<-202 Extensions supported:
<-HDR
<-OVER
<-.
->GROUP group.name
<-211 100031 1 100031 group.name
->OVER 100031-100031
<-500 What?
```

Proper log from news.aioe.org (works as expected)

```
-> CAPABILITIES
<- 101 Capability list:
<- VERSION 2
<- IMPLEMENTATION INN 2.5.2
<- AUTHINFO
<-  SASL
<- HDR
<- LIST ACTIVE ACTIVE.TIMES DISTRIB.PATS HEADERS NEWSGROUPS OVERVIEW.FMT
<- OVER
<- POST
<- READER
<- SASL NTLM DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
<- STARTTLS
<- .
-> STARTTLS
<- 382 Begin TLS negotiation now
-> MODE READER
<- 200 news.aioe.org InterNetNews NNRP server INN 2.5.2 ready (posting ok)
-> CAPABILITIES
<- 101 Capability list:
<- VERSION 2
<- IMPLEMENTATION INN 2.5.2
<- AUTHINFO
<-  USER
<-  SASL
<- 
<- HDR
<- LIST ACTIVE ACTIVE.TIMES DISTRIB.PATS HEADERS NEWSGROUPS OVERVIEW.FMT
<- OVER
<- POST
<- READER
<- SASL NTLM DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
<- .
-> GROUP group.name
<- 211 4540 67027 71566 group.name
-> OVER 67027-71566
<- 224 Overview information for 67027-71566 follows
....
```

Right now, `TIdNNTP` automatically selects OVER when server announces it supports OVER and using `IdNNTP.XOVER` call will issue OVER command. Can this be overridden somehow? Is it worth bothering by doing this sort of legacy support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIdNNTP` is hard-coded to use `OVER` if the server claims to support `OVER`, and likewise for `HDR`. There is no option to change that.  You would have to call `SendCmd()` directly, then you can process the response however you want.

Personally, I would contact astraweb.com and let them know that their NNTP server is broken.  They went to the trouble of implementing the newer `CAPABILITIES` command, but they violated a core requirement of it:

> The server MUST ensure that the capability list accurately reflects the capabilities (including extensions) currently available.

I am not inclined to change Indy's behavior just because one server is non-conforming.  If there are other servers that exhibit the same faulty behavior, then adding a fallback option would make more sense.

Comment: I understand and they are probably tuning their server to work with older clients. I will see to use `SendCmd()` and then `ParseXover()` on the result. Hopefully that won't break the rest of client or other internal variables.

Comment: `TIdNNTP.XOver()` does not change any internal variables, so calling `SendCmd()` directly will not break anything. `TIdNNTP.ParseXOver()` is meant to be called by user code, for use with the overloaded versions of `TIdNNTP.XOver()` that do not trigger the `TIdNNTP.OnXOVER` event.